# Set application to remember theme: dark vs light

Tags: qt, qml

There is this QML setup to remember application theme:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as QQC2

QQC2.ApplicationWindow {

    id: standaloneWindow // ID is required to be able to get properties
    
    Material.theme: Material.Dark // Can be either Dark or Light

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // On launch, read theme from settings file
        standaloneWindow.Material.theme = appSettings.materialTheme
    }

    Component.onDestruction:{
        // On close, write theme to settings file
        appSettings.materialTheme = standaloneWindow.Material.theme
    }

    Settings {
        id: appSettings

        category: "Theme"
        property int materialTheme // Store theme as "int" type in settings file
    }

}
```

#### Problem

At the very first launch (for example when settings file is deleted), the theme cannot be started with `Dark`. At the very first launch, the app *always* starts with `Light` theme, no matter what!

#### Cause

When there is no settings file, the `appSettings.materialTheme` becomes `0` which is default for `int` type. Consequently, `0` is equivalent to `Material.Dark` enum. That's why application always starts at dark mode when there is no settings file.

#### Question

How can I make the application start with light mode, even when there is no settings file?

#### Tried so far

I tried to use `alias` rather than `int`, but `standaloneWindow` doesn't have a property to bind to `Material.theme`:

```
    Settings {
        // ...
        property alias materialTheme: standaloneWindow.???
    }

Any suggestion?
```

Comment: What about `Settings { property int materialTheme: Material.Light }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Mitch , problem got resolved by:

```
    Settings {

        id: appSettings

        category: "Theme"

        // Set dark theme to be default for the very first launch (when settings file is NOT available)
        property int materialTheme: Material.Dark
    }
```